# check the type of an Angular object that can be undefined as well

Tags: angular, typescript, undefined

I am learning Angular and I would like to write a method that returns `true` if the type of the object is `Dog` (it has a `woof` property).

This is what I have so far:

```
export class SomeClass {
   public animal?: Dog | Cat;
   ...
   public isDog() {
    return 'woof' in this.animal;  <-- Object is possibly 'undefined'
  }
}
```

Then I show the content based on the type of the object this way:

```
<div *ngIf="isDog(); then dogCardTemplate else catCardTemplate"></div>
```

My problem is that `this.animal` can be undefined and the following error appears:

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

Could you please help me to solve this in a simple way with as less code line as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to check if is the following:

```js
export class SomeClass {
   public animal?: Dog | Cat;
   
   public isDog() {
      return  this.animal // check to see if its defined first
           && 'woof' in this.animal; // animal type check later
   }

}
```

Why?

Well since the property is optional, we need to make a check to see if it is defined and only after that can we make a check for if its a dog.

Note: if you want to check that it is a cat, you will need to repeat the undefined check.